# Oracle multiple CASE statements evaluating to true

Tags: oracle, case

I thought once the CASE found a match, it would break and return that first match.  However, I'm getting **all** matches from the case statement.  e.g.

```
select distinct PERSON, 
                LOCATION, 
                (case
                  when LOCATION = 'CA' and PHONE is not null
                    then PHONE
                  when LOCATION = 'NY' and PHONE is not null
                    then PHONE
                  when LOCATION = 'FL' and PHONE is not null
                    then PHONE
                  when LOCATION = 'MA' and PHONE is not null
                    then PHONE
                  else '---'
                end)
from DIRECTORY
where LOCATION in
    ( 'CA', 'NY', 'FL', 'MA' );
```

Since the PERSON can have phone numbers in each state, what I want is the **first** phone number found, basically 'ranked' by the order of the states.  What I'm getting is all phone numbers that are found.

Thx...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could assign a rank to each state in subquery, and then retain the highest ranking record for each person:

```
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT
        PERSON, 
        LOCATION,
        PHONE,
        CASE WHEN LOCATION = 'CA' AND PHONE IS NOT NULL THEN 1
             WHEN LOCATION = 'NY' AND PHONE IS NOT NULL THEN 2
             WHEN LOCATION = 'FL' AND PHONE IS NOT NULL THEN 3
             WHEN LOCATION = 'MA' AND PHONE IS NOT NULL THEN 4
             ELSE 5        -- the NULL case
        END AS LOCATION_RANK
    FROM DIRECTORY
    WHERE LOCATION IN ('CA', 'NY', 'FL', 'MA')
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT t.*,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.PERSON ORDER BY t.LOCATION_RANK) rn
    FROM cte1 t
)
SELECT
    t.PERSON,
    t.LOCATION,
    COALESCE(t.PHONE, '---')
FROM cte2 t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

Comment: thanks - it was the 2nd cte I was missing.  Was trying to pull something like max(LOCATION_RANK) from the first cte, but that still returned all rows.  This is great - thanks much...

Answer (score 0):

@TimBielgeleisen's CTE approach may be easier to follow and maintain, but you could do the same thing without any CTEs, using [`keep dense_rank`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/FIRST.htm), though you have to repeat the case expression:

```
select person,
  min(location) keep (dense_rank first order by
    case when phone is null then 2 else 1 end,
    case location when 'CA' then 1 when 'NY' then 2 when 'FL' then 3
      when 'MA' then 4 end) as location,
  coalesce(min(phone) keep (dense_rank first order by
    case when phone is null then 2 else 1 end,
    case location when 'CA' then 1 when 'NY' then 2 when 'FL' then 3
      when 'MA' then 4 end), '---') as phone
from directory
where location in ('CA', 'NY', 'FL', 'MA')
group by person;
```

or you could move the case expression(s) into a single CTE or inline view to make them more maintainable:

```
select person,
  min(location) keep (dense_rank first order by phone_rank, location_rank) as location,
  coalesce(min(phone) keep (dense_rank first order by phone_rank, location_rank),
    '---') as phone
from (
  select person, location, phone,
    case location when 'CA' then 1 when 'NY' then 2 when 'FL' then 3
      when 'MA' then 4 end as location_rank,
    case when phone is null then 2 else 1 end as phone_rank
  from directory
  where location in ('CA', 'NY', 'FL', 'MA')
)
group by person;
```

You're still hitting the table once with any of these approaches, the ranking is just handled a bit differently, so I wouldn't expect a performance difference (but always best to check with your real data, of course).

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct PERSON, 
                LOCATION, 
                (case
                  when LOCATION = 'CA' and PHONE is not null 
                    then PHONE
                    else case
                  when LOCATION = 'NY' and PHONE is not null
                    then PHONE
                    else case
                  when LOCATION = 'FL' and PHONE is not null
                    then PHONE
                    else case
                  when LOCATION = 'MA' and PHONE is not null
                    then PHONE
                  else '---'
                end end end end)
from DIRECTORY
where LOCATION in
    ( 'CA', 'NY', 'FL', 'MA' );
```